# How do you create a global shortcut to launch terminal or open a tab?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, automator

I am trying to create a global shortcut Command Ctrl Shift + T to launch Terminal and open a new tab (unless terminal was not launched yet and if so do not open a new tab)

I am presuming it's in Automator quick action. I can make it launch Terminal, but I can't make it go "new tab" *if needed*.

Comment: I see two distinct issues in your post, "_How do you create a global shortcut to launch terminal or open a tab?_" and "_I can make it launch Terminal, but I can't make it go "new tab" if needed._" For the latter, it would probable be more helpful if you'd edit your question adding in what version of **macOS** and the details of your **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_. An appropriately cropped screen shot and a copy and paste of any written _code_ as well. For the former, if an **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_, look in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Comment: Creating a _global keyboard shortcut_ for an **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ can be problematic in that the particular _keyboard shortcut_ you choose may already be in use by whichever _application_ has focus at the time the _keyboard shortcut_ it pressed. To avoid this issue I use a _third-party application_ named [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) to run my **AppleScript** and _shell script_ scripts with a _keyboard shortcut_. **FastScripts** usually intercepts the _keyboard shortcut_ before any other _application_ it may be assigned to, even it the _app_ has focus.

Comment: I am not affiliated with the developer of **FastScripts**, just a satisfied user for my particular needs.